# Date recognition in text - Latin

Tags: python, nlp

I am working on some Latin texts that contain dates and was using various regex patterns and rule based statements to extract dates. I was wondering if I can use an algorithm to train to extract these dates instead of the method I am currently using. Thanks

This is an extract of my algorithm:

```
def checkLatinDates(i, record, no):
if(i == 0 and isNumber(record[i])): #get deed no
    df.loc[no,'DeedNo'] = record[i] 
rec = record[i].lower()
split = rec.split()
if(split[0] == 'die'):
    items = deque(split)
    items.popleft()
    split = list(items)
if('eodem' in rec): 
    n = no-1
    if(no>1):

        while ( pd.isnull(df.ix[n]['LatinDate'])):                
            n = n-1
        print n
        df['LatinDate'][no] = df.ix[n]['LatinDate']

if(words_in_string(latinMonths, rec.lower()) and len(split)<10):
    if not (dates.loc[dates['Latin'] == split[0], 'Number'].empty):
        day = dates.loc[dates['Latin'] == split[0], 'Number'].iloc[0]
        split[0] = day
        nd = ' '.join(map(str, split))
        df['LatinDate'][no] = nd
    elif(convertArabic(split[0])!= ''):
        day = convertArabic(split[0])
        split[0] = day
        nd = ' '.join(map(str, split))
        df['LatinDate'][no] = nd
```

Comment: We don't know what method you're currently using because you didn't actually share it.

Comment: The Python code you posted has inoorrect indentation and thus won't run. Please [edit] your question to rectify this. Code formatting is really easy - paste the code, select it, type ctrl-K (though this only works in the desktop version of the site; on mobile, you need to manually add four spaces before each code line). See also [Markdown help.](/editing-help)

Answer (score 1):

You could use some machine learning algorithm like adaboost, using [IOB tagging](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inside%E2%80%93outside%E2%80%93beginning_(tagging)) 
adding some context features, like the type of word, a regex to detect if it is obviously a date, the surrounding words type, etc.
[Here](https://www.google.es/amp/s/nlpforhackers.io/named-entity-extraction/amp/) is a tutorial.